# WCF Samples Installation/GettingStarted binding content-type issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I have been attempting to use the WCF samples provided by MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms751514%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get a feel for using WCF. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to run even the most basic WCF sample, which (after following the installation steps), may be found in "C:\WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Basic\GettingStarted". I haven't modified the sample code that was generated by the WCF installer.

When I run the service, I recieve the following error:

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <style>

         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}

         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

         .version {color: gray;}

         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}

         .expandable {'.
```

This, if I interpret it correctly, means that the service is returning html-formatted content instead of xml-formatted data.

After searching on the internet, I found a stack-overflow thread (unable to find link now) which said the problem might be related to the fact that the user "Network Services"--which hosts the service--lacks has very minimal permissions and cannot modify the "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\" folder. When I tried to change permissions, I encountered the following error:

```
An error occured while applying security information to:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\msmq

Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.
```

I also tried changing permissions through the developer command prompt (using a command i found from) via the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>icacls %systemdrive%\inetpub
 /grant %userdomain%\%username%:(OI)(CI)(F) /grant %userdomain%\%username%:F
C:\inetpub: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

though as the above indicates, that clearly didn't work.

I also tried the solution offered in [this related Stack Overflow question, but to no avail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179%28v=nav.70%29.aspx).

I would like to be able to run the samples (and hopefully in the future my own services). What steps should I take to make that a possibility? I have virtually no experience with WCF or server-development, so that it is entirely possible that I made a "trivial" mistake in setting up the service.

Finally, I am working with VS 2012 in Windows 8 Pro, if that affects anything. I ran the sample in debug mode.

I can post the sample code from the service if necessary.

Comment: I also followed the steps outlined on this MSDN page, but they didn't help either: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179(v=nav.70).aspx

Comment: Don't have much experience with Windows 8 but it may be that it doesn't include the .NET 3.0 libraries. The exception indicates the service is failing to find or load the .NET 3.0 version of the System.ServiceModel assembly. The WCF samples are only available for .NET versions 3.0 & 3.5 of the framework.

Comment: After checking on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx), it seems that I already had .Net 3.5 feature activated (as a result of following the original setup instructions), which includes support for v3.0 and earlier. So it seems that is not the problem, unless I am interpreting the instructions there incorrectly (I also had the dev tools enabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to change the loading order between the service and client. Microsoft evidently doesn't set them to load properly by default.

In order to make the fix, select the service library in "Solution Explorer", right click and select the "Set as StartUp Project" option. Running the application through the Windows debugger should now work.

The source of the problem, in this case, seemed to be that the client would run, try to consume the service at the binding address, and then freak out when it recieved an html response instead of the desired xml. The html response was simply sent by the browser, where as the service (if it had been initialized at all) would be waiting to take in the query from the client.

Answer (score 0):

on the service part, you are getting an error

> Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

you are right, that the service is returning html-formatted content instead of xml-formatted data. because it returns an HTML page with the error it encountered during loading.

try to open the endpoint (*.svc file) in the browser, it will most defiantly show the yellow asp error page, there you may find more info on why your service could not start.

Comment: The file service.svc was one line long, with the following text:  <%@ServiceHost language="c#" Debug="true" Service="Microsoft.Samples.GettingStarted.CalculatorService" %>.  
When I open it, I get a page with a red box that reads:  
This page contains the following errors:  
error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. [The rendering is empty.]

Comment: @arturo in Visual studio, right click the SVC file in the solution and select the "view in browser", that way, the service will be built and hosted.

Comment: I recieved the same message. There was nothing written to the output window, however, so it doesn't seem like anything was actually built. Running VS 2012 as admin, I can build the solution (as a normal user I cannot), and when I run it, a command prompt opens up saying "starting silent" and then the aforementioned error.

Comment: sooo. it's a self hosting service. look at the web config or in code, to find an URL to the service with a port number, the navigate to the address, appending the mentioned service file name. something similar to http://localhost:23548/service.svc, but with different port number. alternatively, you can look at the code of the client application, to find out where it is sending requests.

Comment: the client config points to "http://localhost/servicemodelsample/service.svc". I tried running the service by changing the load-order (making the service load first by using "Set as StartUp Project" setting from solution explorer), and it seems that has resolved the issue, almost inexplicably. Do this "solution" merit its own answer?

Comment: well, the whole issue was because your client application was loading faster than the service, which resulted in the service responding with an error (as it did not load correctly at the time it was requested.) that way, i would recon that your solution is in fact a solution.